# When writing parquet files to s3 NoSuchMethodError :void org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, parquet

When I try to write the dataframe to s3 as parquet, I always get an error like below. In the s3 bucket, an empty folder is generated automatically every time, but there is no parquet file. How can I solve it please?(I am running the program locally, and there is no ec2 instance )

**Here is my code:**

```
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").appName("Test")
                .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", "false").config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
                .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem").getOrCreate();

        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", AWS_KEY);
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", AWS_SECRET_KEY);
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com");
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true");
        spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl.disable.cache", "false");

        Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read().format("jdbc")
                .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").option("url", url)
                .option("user", user).option("password", password).option("dbtable", dbtable).load();

        jdbcDF.write().parquet("s3a://******************.parquet");
```

**Here is the error**

```
   22/02/10 11:39:31 INFO JDBCRDD: closed connection
    22/02/10 11:39:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService, int, boolean)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:1239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    22/02/10 11:39:31 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (JPC20537955.jp.sony.com executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService, int, boolean)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:1239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    
    22/02/10 11:39:31 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
    22/02/10 11:39:31 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
    22/02/10 11:39:31 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
    22/02/10 11:39:31 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 1: Stage cancelled
    22/02/10 11:39:31 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (parquet at SparkTest.java:56) failed in 0.596 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (JPC20537955.jp.sony.com executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService, int, boolean)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:1239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    
    Driver stacktrace:
    22/02/10 11:39:31 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: parquet at SparkTest.java:56, took 0.598673 s
    22/02/10 11:39:31 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job 6f6f0088-f781-44b2-8d86-15361f2bc129.
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (JPC20537955.jp.sony.com executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService, int, boolean)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:1239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    
    Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2352)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2591)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2533)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:898)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:781)
        at sparkTest.SparkTest.main(SparkTest.java:56)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService, int, boolean)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.create(S3AFileSystem.java:1239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.hadoop.util.SemaphoredDelegatingExecutor.<init>(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService, int, boolean)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl.StoreContext.createThrottledExecutor(StoreContext.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl.DeleteOperation.<init>(DeleteOperation.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.delete(S3AFileSystem.java:2468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.cleanupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:532)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.abortJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:551)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.abortJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:242)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:250)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:781)
        at sparkTest.SparkTest.main(SparkTest.java:56)
```

**Here are the dependencies I use.**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spark.version>3.2.0</spark.version>
    <hadoop.version>3.3.0</hadoop.version>
    <aws.version>1.12.153</aws.version>
    <spark.pom.scope>compile</spark.pom.scope>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
        <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.153</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-avro -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
        <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Any luck with the issue ?

Comment: any luck with this error @seven or Surya

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and my workaround was to use ***hadoop-aws:3.2.2*** version.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
        SparkSession
        .builder
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.2')
        .config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')
    .getOrCreate()
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

there's clearly some dependency problems between hadoop-aws and the hadoop-common ; you`ll have to track them down.

Also, that release of hadoop was against AWS sdk 1.11.something, not 1.12. That is not the cause of this stack trace, but you are safer going with the explicit dependencies of hadoop-aws than being the person qualifying aws sdk release compatibility

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if my answer will help, but...

I was having similar issue when writing to AWS S3. I was being able to read, but the writing was failing.

I was using `pyspark 3.2.1`. After lots of different attempts of pulling different versions of `hadoop-aws` and `aws-java-sdk`, I upgraded `pyspark` to version `3.3.1` and used jars versions:

`org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1`
`com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.469`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue combination of the following versions fixed, spark-core_2.12 version 3.2.1; hadoop-common & hadoop-client version 3.2.1 and hadoop-aws 3.2.3.

Comment: This does not fix the problem with `spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop3.2` release. Here is my `spark-submit` `--packages` option: `--packages "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.2.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.967,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.3,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.2.1,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.2.1" \`. Any idea please?